# Initialization of std::string from std::vector<unsigned char> causes error

Tags: c++, vector, stdstring

In C++ we can create a vector from another vector via
 `std::vector<unsigned char> tmp_1 { &some_vector[i] , &some_vector[j] };`

Question : Is there any way to do the same for `std::string`?
 Something like:

```
std::string tmp2 { &some_vector[i] , &some_vector[j] };
```

Attempts to use constructor from documentation always return error;

*Note:*
*some_vector is the vector of unsigned chars

**UPD**: Found answer: had typo so tried to access [-1] element.

Comment: Check out the documentation or the code to find out if there's a constructor overload that suits your needs.

Comment: Don't ask before trying...

Comment: Tried -  read access violation inside xstring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`std::string` has [several constructors](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string), some of which can be used to construct the string from a `std::vector`, eg:

```
// using a char* pointer and a size...
std::string tmp2( reinterpret_cast<char*>(&some_vector[i]), j-i );
```

```
// using char* pointers as iterators...
std::string tmp2( &some_vector[i], &some_vector[j] );
```

```
// using vector iterators...
std::string tmp2( some_vector.begin()+i, some_vector.begin()+j );
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/RUxxgF)

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
std::string tmp2 { &some_vector[i] , &some_vector[j] };
```

should work for `std::vector` but I would prefer more readable and safer solution:

```
std::string tmp2 { std::next( some_container, i ) , std::next( some_container.begin(), j ) };
```

which should work on any container with type, that can be convertible to `char`. For example if you or somebody else later would decide to replace `std::vector<char>` to `std::deque<char>` for whatever reason, your program will suddenly and what is more dangerous quietly start to be unpredictable with `&container[i]`.